# getDownloadUrl en Android me devuelve null

Tags: android, firebase, glide

en esta ocasión, intento recuperar imágenes que se ha subido directamente a Firebase Storage, se ha generado una estructura para la base de datos de la siguiente manera:

**BASE DE DATOS**

```
{
  "categorias" : {
    "categoria1" : {
      "nombre" : "Licores",
      "ruta" : "categoria1.jpg"
    },
    "categoria2" : {
      "nombre" : "Bebidas no alcoholicas",
      "ruta" : "categoria2.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

**LAS REGLAS DE ACCESO A LOS DATOS**

Las reglas que se han determinado para el acceso a los datos son las siguientes:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "categorias":{
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
      ".write": "auth.uid != null"      
    },
    "perfiles":{
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"      
      }
    }      
  }
}
```

**EN EL CÓDIGO**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderCategorias viewHolderCategorias, int position) {

    viewHolderCategorias.nombreCategoria.setText(listaCategorias.get(position).getNombre());

    rutaImagen = storageRef.child(listaCategorias.get(position).getRuta());
    rutaImagen.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            myUrl = uri.toString();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
```

Pero a pesar de haber leído la información que hay en Android Developers y haber tomado el código que allí sugiere, pues el getDownloadUrl devuelve null ya que jamás ingresa a ejecutar esa porción del código que se encuentra en el onSuccess, lo que pretendo es enviar esa url a Glide para mostrar la imagen, ya que lo que hice antes fue enviar directamente un StorageReference (rutaImagen) no me funciona debido a que este me devuelve la dirección de almacenamiento (gs://) y no la dirección de descarga (https://), entonces en base a esa dirección de almacenamiento pretendo llegar a la dirección de descarga. ¿Alguna sugerencia de como lo puedo lograr?

Les agradecería de antemano.

Comment: Hola, pero no haz guardado el link de descarga de Firebase Storage en tu Firebase database :P? guardalo alli cuando lo subes, este te retorna el link :D

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, pero ¿Entonces la solución es que al momento de almacenar la imagen hacerlo conjuntamente con la url? y no hacerlo por código con el StorageReference y obtenerlo de aquí?

Comment: En un rato te respondo con mi solucion :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero guardar el link que te retorna Firebase Storage al subir tu archivo.

```
//Se parece a este :D
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/software-25c1e.appspot.com/o/xxxx.docx?alt=media&token=155bf282-cdff-4693-9755-39cdb4232b65
```

Segundo, ya con el url de descarga realiza la descarga de esta manera. Debes pedir permisos para poder usar el Storage (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

En Java

```
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("URL ARCHIVO");
    //Nombre de la carpeta donde vas a guardar los archivos dentro de tu storage
    File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Asesorias Ulima");
    if (!rootPath.exists()) {
        rootPath.mkdirs();
    }
    final File localFile = new File(rootPath, "NOMBRE_DEL_ARCHIVO.PNG");
    if (!localFile.exists()) {
        storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                openFile(localFile);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    //Funcion para poder abrir el archivo que haz descargado
    public void openFile(File url) {

        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                url.getAbsoluteFile());

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
            // Word document
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
            // PDF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
            // Powerpoint file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
            // Excel file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".zip") || url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
            // WAV audio file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/x-wav");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
            // RTF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
            // WAV audio file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
            // GIF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
            // JPG file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
            // Text file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") || url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(".mpe") || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")) {
            // Video files
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
        } else {
            //if you want you can also define the intent type for any other file
            //additionally use else clause below, to manage other unknown extensions
            //in this case, Android will show all applications installed on the device
            //so you can choose which application to use
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

En Kotlin

```
    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    val storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("URL DEL ARCHIVO")
    //Nombre de la carpeta donde vas a guardar los archivos dentro de tu storage
    val rootPath = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Asesorias Ulima")
    if (!rootPath.exists()) {
        rootPath.mkdirs()
    }
    val localFile = File(rootPath, "NOMBRE_DEL_ARCHIVO.PNG")
    if (!localFile.exists()) {
        storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
            openFile(localFile)
            //  updateDb(timestamp,localFile.toString(),position);
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            toast("local tem file not created  created \" + $exception")
        }
    }


//Funcion para poder abrir el archivo que haz descargado
fun openFile(url:File) {

    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
            url.absoluteFile)

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

    if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
        // Word document
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
        // PDF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
        // Powerpoint file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
        // Excel file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".zip") || url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/x-wav")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
        // RTF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
        // GIF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
        // JPG file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
        // Text file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain")
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") || url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(".mpe") || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")) {
        // Video files
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*")
    } else {
        //if you want you can also define the intent type for any other file
        //additionally use else clause below, to manage other unknown extensions
        //in this case, Android will show all applications installed on the device
        //so you can choose which application to use
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*")
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    startActivity(intent)

}
```

Segundo en tu manifest poner lo siguiente.

```
//Para los permisos
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Tercero crea el archivo provider_paths dentro de la carpeta xml dentro de la carpeta res.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```